# Migrate user profiles when taking W2K8 out of a domain and into a workgroup

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration, user-profile

I have a box currently sitting in an AD domain. I need to remove it from said domain and drop it into a workgroup.

I don't want to lose the 2-3 user profiles on the box.

I think I could use USMT to migrate, but it seems like overkill. Is there an easy way to copy the profiles over so they will usable once I put the machine in workgroup-land? Something as simple as copying over \users\ and some reg entries, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time just ensuring the local user (workgroup user) has read/write access to their profile folder in `\Users\` will work OK. Of course the folder cannot have a name like `tim.DOMAIN`, if my new local (workgroup) user was named `tim` the folder would need the same name.

Steps:

1. add the new "local user", `computername\user` opposed to `domain\user`
2. ensure the new "local user" has read/write access to the folder in question
3. Remove from domain and logoff (reboot is best)
4. Login as new "local user"

Comment: Perfect - in my case. folder names are simply users\<username> vs. users\<username>.domain. So it sounds like all I need to do is put this sucker back into a workgroup and then recreate the domain user as a workgroup user on the local machine?

Comment: Updating my answer with steps..

Answer (score 0):

Another note: When I need to migrate profiles from user machines, I use the free version of ProfileWizard: http://www.forensit.com/profwiz-faqs.html

Comment: Interesting, but this seems to be a solution for migrating to a domain account vs. a workgroup account?